# How to convert datatype when read a csv file using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, sqlalchemy

I want export foo.csv to my database by using pandas.I use sqlalchemy for operating sqlite, and  declare a model just like the following code:

```
class House:
 __table__name='house'
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,index=True,primary_key=True)
    city=db.Column(db.String(128),index=True,default="")
```

When I try to use pandas.read_csv to deal with that--here is an example:`df=pd.read_csv('path/foo.csv',error_bad_lines=False)`I got an error :

```
sqlite3.IntegrityError: datatype mismatch
```

It seems that pandas read data as string. I also search the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684951/pandas-read-csv-dtype-read-all-columns-but-few-as-string) for converting data type.It does help but still can not solve my problem as it occurs:

```
     File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1173, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens
    TypeError: Cannot cast array from dtype('O') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10
```

here is the code I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd

col_names=pd.read_csv('path/foo.csv',error_bad_lines=False,nrows=0).columns
type_dict={'price':int,'id':int}
type_dict.update({col:str for col in col_names if col not in type_dict})
con=sqlalchemy.create_engine(Config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI,echo=True)
df=pd.read_csv('path/foo.csv',error_bad_lines=False,dtype=type_dict)
df.to_sql(name='house',con=con,if_exists='append',index=False)
```

attention: I know there is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-data-type-of-columns-in-pandas) similar to this. But I can not see it could help solve this.
I want to know how to solve this ,or are there some other decent ways to export csv to database?

added my part of data:

```
id,title,unit,price,latitude
1, US Fut town, 501#2,500,31.199851740354852
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It would be helpful to see a sample of your data; the error you posted indicates that you're trying to convert non-numeric data to float

Comment: I can provide some data in my foo.csv if needed.