# How to read data as a text only in pandas python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, boto3

I have many csv files in S3 and i want to read only 7 columns from each files through pandas. But  in the output csv files for numerical column I am getting decimal values as well.like for count 9.0,6.0 but i want to read everything as a text only. like 9 and 6. I tried from pd.read_fwf but still issue is not resolved. can someone help me out please.

```
cols=["name","Phone","cost","count","location","location1", "family_count"]

reader = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(body), delimiter=',', quotechar='"',
                         encoding='utf8', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True, 
                          usecols=cols)
reader.reset_index()

csv_buffer = BytesIO()

reader.to_csv(csv_buffer, index=False)
```

I tried to specify dtype=object

```
reader = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(body), delimiter=',', quotechar='"',
                     encoding='utf8', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True, 
                      usecols=cols,dtype=object)
```

but then i an getting type error:"Data type not understood"

Comment: Have you tried the dtype argument in pd.read_csv? It will help you to force the data types of incoming data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas read\_csv dtype read all columns but few as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684951/pandas-read-csv-dtype-read-all-columns-but-few-as-string)

Comment: NO I want to read everything as a text

Comment: Hi @Mahendra I tried but getting Type error

Comment: @RavikantPandey then its difficult to comment without looking at the data. It would be great if you can provide a sample of your input data