performance issue converting csv file to xlsx in python
I use the code below to convert csv file to xlsx file.
For a csv file that is 61MB in size, contains 18 columns and 438,000 rows,
it took 3:30 mins, the xlsx file is 29MB in size.
For a csv file that is 480 MB in size, contains 95 columns and 760,000 rows,
it took 30mins, the xlsx file is 276MB in size
import glob
import csv
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

def create_excel_file_from_csv(csv_file_path, new_file_path):
    """Create an Excel file from a CSV file"""
    for csvfile in glob.glob(csv_file_path):
        workbook = Workbook(new_file_path, {'constant_memory': True,'strings_to_numbers':False})
        workbook.use_zip64()
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        with open(csvfile, 'rt', encoding='utf8') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for r, row in enumerate(reader):
                for c, col in enumerate(row):
                    worksheet.write(r, c, col)
        workbook.close()

Does anyone know how to improve the performance?
I am happy to change other package or method if required.

I'm not very familiar with Workbook, but do you really need to create and close it every loop? can't it be done once? you can also parallelize the process.

it is only one csv file at a time, so the top for can be ignored for this case.

Which part takes the most time? Investigate! Either simply using the time function or using some profiler.

Also, there are functions write_row and write_column which might be faster than repeatedly writing to single cell.

@Jeyekomon The  write_row() and write_column() methods aren't faster. They are just simple loops like the OPs code.

I think this is just the performance that you can expect. It scales as expected from ~3 mins to 30 mins for a 10x data increase. There isn't anything that can be optimized in your code. Switching to Pandas might speed up the CSV part but it won't speed up the xlsx writing part because that also uses XlsxWriter and it looks like that is where the bottleneck is.

@jmcnamara I tested the pandas to_excel one, the performance is similar. Because it uses XlsxWriter. Your comment confirmed my thinking.

@Jeyekomon The write_row() method isn't faster. I tested it. it matches what
jmcnamara said.

@Pingpong Just one last tip - If you know the type of your values beforehand, you can use some specialized function such as write_string. Looking at the source code for the general write function, there is some type checking overhead.

@Jeyekomon, thx for the info. But we don't know the data type. It is used for any file with different data type.

Iterating through each cell is not a good approach.
use pandas read csv, then use to_excel method.
Read:
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict


dt = defaultdict(lambda: str)
# or
# dt = str
df = pd.read_csv(..., dtype= dt)

Write:
import time
from itertools import product
from string import ascii_letters

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyexcelerate as acc

n_row = 1_000_000
n_column = 50

rng = np.random.default_rng()
rng = rng.spawn(n_column)

columns = (a + b for a, b in product(ascii_letters, repeat=2))
data = {next(columns): rng[i].random(dtype=np.float64, size=n_row) for i in range(n_column)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, dtype=np.float64)
print("fake dataframe finished.")

t1 = time.monotonic()
with pd.ExcelWriter(
    "result.xlsx",
    engine="xlsxwriter",
    engine_kwargs={"options": {"constant_memory": True, "strings_to_numbers": False, "use_zip64": True}},
) as f:
    df.to_excel(f, index=False)
print(f"df.to_excel {time.monotonic() - t1:.3f}")

t1 = time.monotonic()
wb = acc.Workbook()
wb.new_sheet("test", data=df.values.tolist())
wb.save("result2.xlsx")
print(f"pyexcelerate {time.monotonic() - t1:.3f}")

Result:
df.to_excel 143.084
pyexcelerate 138.927

There is very little improvement that can be made. The actual situation I have encountered is to read csv and then store it into a parquet file.

I tried that already, it changes the formatting even 'strings_to_numbers': False

You should specify dtype in read_csv. You can refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77905736/10294812

I tested the pandas to_excel one, the performance is similar. Because it uses XlsxWriter. Plus, it removed decimal places, and I don't know how to disable it.

I re-implemented the code for exporting Excel in Rust language, and it took 64 seconds to export the same data as Python.

My project can only use Python. Thanks for the info.
